# i am trying to disable and enable button when it is checked and not

Tags: java, android

/*i am trying to disable and enable button when it is checked and not... but in OnCheckedChangedListener() shows Class 'Anonymous class derived from OnCheckedChangedListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method' onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton, bolean)' in 'OnCheckedChangeLisner'*/

package com.example.amby.mobihut;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.R.attr.start;

public class SignInScreen extends AppCompatActivity  {
    AsyncResponse delegate;
    Button btn;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in_screen);

        //context = this;
        //final Context context = this;


        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btn.setEnabled(false);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    btn.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    btn.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
                                            }
        );

    }
    //public void processFinish(String output){}
}
```

Comment: please answer...

Answer (score 0):

try using on `setOnClickListener`

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById (R.id.yourId);

checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
            //is chkIos checked?
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                     //Case 1
    }
    else 
      //case 2

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the onCheckedChangeListener. Add @Override above **public void onCheckedChanged(..)** . Here in this way:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Close the thread and up vote the answer if your issue is solved.